# binding app property to own dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf

I made own dependency property like this

```
    public bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(VisibleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            System.Windows.Visibility v = value == true ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            SetValue(VisibleProperty, value);
            border.Visibility = v;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Visible", typeof(bool), typeof(SpecialMenuItem), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

I'm binding my app property to it, but no luck.
App property(app.xaml.cs) and binding:

```
    public bool IsGamePlaying
    {
        get
        {
            return isGamePlaying;
        }
        set
        {
            isGamePlaying = value;
        }
    }
    private bool isGamePlaying;

<my:SpecialMenuItem ... Visible="{Binding Path=IsGamePlaying, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}" />
```

When I'm in debug, it reads the IsGamePlaying property, but doesn't make attempt to set the Visible property

How make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include any logic in your dependency property wrapper. WPF will, where possible, directly call GetValue/SetValue rather than use your CLR property. You should include any extraneous logic by using metadata in your dependency property. For example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Visible", typeof(bool), typeof(SpecialMenuItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnVisibleChanged));

private static void OnVisibleChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // logic here will be called whenever the Visible property changes
}
```

The CLR wrapper is merely a convenience for consumers of your class.

Comment: can you make example of using logic in metadata? why there's such a limitation?

Comment: It's not a limitation - it's a feature (performance). See my post for example. You may also want to read about coercion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx

Comment: You have no change notification on your IsGamePlaying property. You need to go and read on the basics of data binding in WPF before you go any further.